# HTML table sent via Ajax to PHP email loses 0 values

Tags: php, html, ajax, html-table, html-email

I'm not sure if this is an ajax or PHP problem but... I have a basic HTML table, I dynamically load some values to it using jQuery and it displays them all fine on the front end, I then send it with some other tables via ajax:

```
//activate email option
$("#sendEmail").click(function(){
    var emailadd=prompt("Please enter your email address");
    var data = {
        email: emailadd,
        message: $("#cresult").html(),
        message2: $("#cscores").html(),
        message3: $("#ffc").html()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendEmail.php",
        data: data
    });
});
```

to a basic PHP email script:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html'; charset=utf-8 . "\r\n";
$to      = $_POST["email"];
$subject = 'Stand Alone Algorithm Results';
$message = $_POST["message2"]. $_POST["message"]. $_POST["message3"];
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

And it all works lovely... except when it arrives in the inbox any table cell that contained a value of "0" is now empty?

I think there may be a Tolkeinesk Ajax goblin that eats 0's living in the dark void between client and server!

Any inspiration gratefully received.

As an update the HTML table in question is in message2: $("#cscores").html(), the html is:

```
<div id="cscores">
<H3>Scores</H3>
<table id="scorestable" border="2">

<th>No</th><th>Item Description</th><th>Score</th><th></th>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Overactive, aggressive, disruptive or agitated behaviour</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Non-accidental self-injury</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Problem drinking or drug taking</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Cognitive Problems</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>Physical Illness or disability problems</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>Hallucinations and Delusions</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>Depressed mood *</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>Other mental and behavioural problems *</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>Relationships</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>Activities of daily living</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>Living conditions</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td><td>Occupation and Activities</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>Strong Unreasonable Beliefs</td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td>A</td><td>Agitated behaviour/expansive mood</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td>Repeat Self-Harm</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td>Safeguarding other children and vulnerable dependant adults</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td><td>Engagement</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>E</td><td>Vulnerability</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I am loading the empty td's with text via jquery:

```
/add scores to scorestable table for email
var r=1;
$.each( $(".scorebox"), function() { 
var x=(this.innerHTML); 
$("#scorestable tr:eq("+r+") td:eq(2)").text(x);
r++;
});

//add item 8 problem type to scorestable
var prob=$("#probtype").text();
$("#scorestable tr:eq(8) td:eq(3)").html(prob);
```

Incidentally this is for a nursing tool as my occupation is nursing not coding so never assume I have correctly covered the basics, and don't be too harsh on shoddy coding.

Comment: use `.val()` or `.text()` rather than `.html()` . Please check

Comment: Why would `.html()` remove `0`?

Comment: Is that your real PHP script? Do you do any validation with `empty($_POST['fieldname'])`? A zero value is empty.

Comment: I havent added any validation yet, i was trying to cut it back to as little as possible to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: You have a syntax error on the `Content-type` line. `charset=utf-8` should be inside the quotes.

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: I am using .html() so it sends the formatted table, but i have tried .val() and .text() in the jquery that populates the table.

Comment: Well I have corrected the syntax, thanks for pointing that out @Barmar, and did the dump you suggested which was fine. So having traced it forward to that point I then i tried testing on different email services and got: Roundcube loses the 0 values, squirrel mail shows the values but looses the outer table, AOL mail shows nothing at all, hotmail, google and others work fine! I guess this is just down to how each treats HTML embedded content??

Comment: Is the email you're sending really valid HTML? I don't see you putting any tags in `$message`. Can you post a sample of `$message`?